# SQL Group by latest entry

Tags: sql

I have three tables

```
table1      
PCName      PCID
PC1     001
PC2     002
PC3     003

table2
PCID        LastOnline
001     01.02.13
002     05.01.13
003     04.03.13

table3
PCID        PatchInstall
001     03.02.13
001     05.02.13
001     01.02.13
002     06.02.13
002     08.02.13            
003     01.02.13
003     09.02.13
003     10.02.13

I can get the information together like this
PCID    PCName  LastOnline  PatchInstall
001     PC1     01.02.13    03.02.13
001     PC1     01.02.13    05.02.13
001     PC1     01.02.13    01.02.13
002     PC2     05.01.13    06.02.13
002     PC2     05.01.13    08.02.13            
003     PC3     04.03.13    01.02.13
003     PC3     04.03.13    09.02.13
003     PC3     04.03.13    10.02.13
```

But I would like to only have on record per PC with the most recent PatchInstall date. I have tried doing it with the GROUP BY command but haven't had any luck.

Has anybody got an idea how to make it possible?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.pcid,
  t2.name,
  t2.LastOnLine,
  t3.LatestPatchInstall
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.pcid = t2.pcid
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT pcid, MAX(PatchInstall) AS LatestPatchInstall
  FROM table3
  GROUP BY pcid
) AS t3 ON t1.pcid = t3.pcid
```

Comment: thanks worked like a charm. I didn't test the other options but thanks to everybody for their input.

Comment: @user2206898 - You're welcome any time :) test it and if there is anything goes wrong don't hesitate to ask again :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `table1` and `table2` are in a 1-to-1 relationship, this is as easy as using the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT t1.PCID, PCName, LastOnline, MAX(PatchInstall) AS PatchInstall
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.PCID = t2.PCID
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.PCID = t3.PCID
GROUP BY t1.PCID, PCName, LastOnline
```

If it is not a 1-to-1 relationship, you will get one row for each `table1`-`table2` pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
  max(PatchInstall) over (partition by PCName)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way of doing it would be using `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT T1.PCName,
          T2.LastOnline,
          T3.PatchInstall,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.PCID ORDER BY T3.PatchInstall DESC) AS RNK
   FROM Table1 T1
   INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.PCID = T1.PCID
   INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.PCID = T1.PCID
)


SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE RNK = 1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ad69/18)